# Sublime Text Vertical Line Highlighter

Tags: notepad++, sublimetext3

In the good ol' Notepad++ days, I had this luxury of Bracket Highlighting, in which even the grey `vertical lines connecting the brackets` used to change to Red (or get highlighted), giving me a good view of the whole block.

Is there a way to have that in `Sublime Text 3` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to do this using [`BracketHighlighter`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/BracketHighlighter). More recent releases have the `"content_highlight_bar"` and `"align_content_highlight_bar"` settings, which allow you to have a vertical line connecting your paired brackets. You'll need to have [configured your highlight styles](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter#configuring-highlight-style) so that brackets are marked with a unique color.

It's worth reading through the entire BracketHighlighter [README](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter#readme) as well as all the settings in **`Preferences -> Package Settings -> Bracket Highlighter -> Bracket Settings-Default`** to see what's possible. You'll need to play with your color scheme if you want to add BracketHighlighter-specific settings, but that's not too hard if you use the [tmTheme Editor](http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com).